# Loading Styles With Webpack causes styles to blink on initial load

Tags: sass, webpack

I'm currently working on a project and Im attempting to load my scss/sass through webpack. I'm currently loading it in successfully using the following libs:

- `node-sass`
- `sass-loader`
- `css loader`
- `style-loader`

I am able to `require`/`import` the styles in successfully but the problem occurs that when I load up the application the page loads without the styles for about 1.5 seconds and then after the page "blinks" and the styles finally load in.

Is there a way to get around this through webpack? I have heard of `ExtractTextPlugin` and a few others but I've tried to implement it by looking at article examples and github examples but they don't seem to work by using `require`/`import` where they are needed. I'd like to only require the styles based on my react component needs. Not loading any styles that the components don't need.

Comment: Is your whole page a React app? In that case this shouldn't be happening because webpack makes sure required modules (styles in this case) are loaded first. But if only a part of your app is in React and all of your styles are loaded via JS, you should probably split them or use ExtractTextPlugin. Could you provide more information about your app?

Comment: Yea the whole page is a React app, I find it pretty odd that it happens :/
Im using react, react-router, and redux. Any other information you might want to know? @silvenon

Comment: I think you have to isolate the issue a bit. Just take away parts of your app which are not the styles so you can post a bare minimum of webpack configuration which causes this issue. Either that or post the link to the repo.

Comment: `sass-loader` [mentions](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader/tree/e81fa62974556049fc5063c11089fb97581d9410#extracting-stylesheets) that FOUC might be a problem and recommends extracting the stylesheet as a separate file in production. What exactly doesn't work when you try using the `ExtractTextPlugin`?

Answer (score 2):

You have (at least) two options to prevent this FOUC (Flash of unstyled content):

1. Use a plugin like [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) or [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to extract the compiled CSS into a separate file that you can load normally in your `<head>` ([read more](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/tree/e81fa62974556049fc5063c11089fb97581d9410#extracting-stylesheets)) or
2. Hide your content, using CSS, until styles are ready, the loaded styles should contain the styles that will make the content visible.